# How do I fill razor DropDownListFor with Javascript list of object MVC 5 C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want a dropdownlist that will be filled according to the Id chosen from another dropdownlist (Cascade Dropdownlist) and I would like to be able to return my object list sorted in Javascript and then give it to my dropdownlistfor but I don't know how.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
     <label for="@Html.IdFor(model => model.CoastId)">
              @Strings.CoastField
     </label>
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CoastId, Model.CoastList, SharedStrings.SelectDefaultOptionText, new { @class = "form-control" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CoastId)
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <label for="@Html.IdFor(model => model.VillageId)">
                Village
      </label>
      @*DropdownListFor(model => model.VillageId, *****MyJavascriptList*****)*@
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VillageId)
</div>
```

I then take my village list and send it to my JavaScript file in JSON format.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var villageList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.AllVillageList));
         Form.init(villageList);
      </script>
```

Then, I put an onchange event on the first dropdownlist with the id "CoastId".

```
var Form = (function ($,_) {
var init = function(villageArray) {
    $('#UserName').focus();
    if (villageArray !== "") {
        $("#CoastId").change(function () {
            model.ReturnedVillages = _.filter(villageArray, function (obj) { return obj.RegionId === parseInt($("#CoastId").val()); });
            console.log(model.ReturnedVillages);
        });
    }
};
return {
    init: init
};
})(jQuery,_);
```

[My "ReturnedVillage" object is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZTN0.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @MathD have you tried to use a Select List element with a ViewBag, then on the `onchange` method of the Select List you can take the selected value and send it to the next action via AJAX to fill the second List, [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/bind-dropdown-on-selection-change-of-another-dropdown-in-mvc/) is an example